# A problem on Fourier Transform

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-analysis

Find the Fourier transform for

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}-x&0\leq x\leq 1\\x-\frac{1}{2}&1<x\leq 2\end{cases}.$

The Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is given by

$T(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux}f(x) dx.$

How do we find for the above problem? A small hint would be appreciable. Kindly help me out!

Edit:  \begin{align*}
T(u)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^1 e^{iux}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right) dx+\int_{1}^2e^{iux}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\left[\frac{e^{iux}}{2iu}\right]_0^1-\left(\left[\frac{xe^{iux}}{iu}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{e^{iux}}{iu}dx\right)+\left[\frac{xe^{iux}}{iu}\right]_1^2-\int_1^2\frac{e^{iux}}{iu}dx-\left[\frac{e^{iux}}{2iu}\right]_1^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{e^{iu}}{2iu}-\frac{1}{2iu}-\frac{e^{iu}}{iu}+\left[\frac{e^{iux}}{i^2u^2}\right]_0^1+\frac{2e^{2iu}}{iu}-\frac{e^{iu}}{iu}-\left[\frac{e^{iux}}{i^2u^2}\right]_1^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{2iu}}{iu}+\frac{e^{iu}}{2iu}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{e^{iu}}{2iu}-\frac{1}{2iu}-\frac{e^{iu}}{iu}+\frac{e^{iu}}{i^2u^2}-\frac{1}{i^2u^2}+\frac{2e^{2iu}}{iu}-\frac{e^{iu}}{iu}-\frac{e^{2iu}}{i^2u^2}+\frac{e^{iu}}{i^2u^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{2iu}}{iu}+\frac{e^{iu}}{2iu}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{3e^{2iu}-1}{2iu}-\frac{2e^{iu}-e^{2iu}-1}{i^2u^2}\right]
\end{align*}

Am I doing correctly?

Comment: There is no problem. Roll up your sleeves and compute.

Comment: @AnneBauval Please see me edits, am I proceeding correct?

Comment: Correct except the minus sign in front of the last fraction.

Comment: And there is a $-\frac{e^{iu}}{iu}$ missing, on the last line only.